# .NET 4.5 causing FatalExecutionEngineError with std::string and System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Tags: .net, c++-cli

We have an app that uses C++/CLI, and one part of the code goes roughly like this:

```
void foo(const std::string& connStr)
{
    gcroot<SqlConnection^> conn = gcnew SqlConnection();
    conn->ConnectionString = gcnew String(connStr.c_str());
}
```

If I have .NET 4.5 installed, a FatalExecutionEngineError exception is thrown in SqlConnection::ConnectionString::set, with the top of the callstack in bids::bids().

Here's the interesting part:  We use VS2010 and msvcr100.dll, but if I look at the dependencies of C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll, it shows it depends on msvcr110_0400.dll.  And indeed, I can see all 3 of those modules get loaded when the app runs.

My guess was there was some kind of CRT version mismatch, so I uninstalled .NET 4.5 and installed 4.0.  clr.dll now shows a dependency on msvcr100_0400.dll, and the app runs without throwing that exception.

What I'm most confused about is "clr.dll", and why the exact same version (4.0.30319) has two different msvcr___.dll dependencies for two versions of .NET.  Any thoughts on whether this was actually causing the exception, or maybe it was something else with .NET 4.5?

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: The _400.dll copy is a private copy of the CRT that is used by the jitter and the CLR.  The .NET 4.0 version was built with VS2010, The 4.5 version was built with VS2012.  Not otherwise different from msvcrt.dll, a private copy for Windows executables.  And msvcr100.dll is a private copy used by your code.  No, it has nothing to do with .NET, you are corrupting the GC heap with your code.  Arbitrarily changing the .NET version didn't fix that bug.  It just hid it.  The only thing obvious about your code snippet is that you use gcroot<> complete wrong.  Not the source of the corruption.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, Hans.  I think the gcroot<> is there because SqlConnection is actually templated, and not the SqlConnection concrete type.  I will examine the code for sources of heap corruption.  Thanks again.

Comment: @BigHands79 I am from Microsoft .NET Framework Compatibility Team I'd like to understand this better. Could you contact us on netfx45compat at Microsoft dot com? Thanks!